# Как определить наличие побочного ударения?

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия, сложные-слова

В каком слове есть побочное ударение? Как определить наличие побочного ударения?

> свободолюбивый
>
> своевольный
>
> свежескошенный
>
> самовольный
>
> слезоточивый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если основное ударение обычно определяется уверенно, то побочное можно заметить по дискомфорту, возникающему при попытке произнесения без ударения одной из оставшихся гласных сложного слова. Здесь это можно ощутить в словах "**свежескошенный**" (в первом слоге гласная всегда уверенно произносится как "е", т.е. как в ударном слоге) и в меньшей степени в слове "**свободолюбивый**" (слог "-бо-" можно произнести с ударением или без него, в зависимости от темпа речи). Это может быть связано как с устойчивостью ударения в основе слова, участвующего в образовании сложного слова (при образовании нового слова оно стремится передать звучание исходного), так и с потребностью комфортно (с сохранением ритма речи) распределить акценты в многосложном слове.

Answer (score 2):

> В каком слове есть побочное ударение?

На мой взгляд -- во всех представленных. Но...

> Как определить наличие побочного
> ударения?

В словаре Аванесова только в одном из этих слов выделено побочное ударение:

*св**Е**жеск**О**шенный* (побочное -- на первом слоге).